# how to have ui-select placeholder return when ui-select is disabled

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am using ui-select for a dropdown select that follows the example demo code very closely. The ui-select is all working great. I now am adding an angular-material checkbox. The intent is to have the checkbox enable/disable the dropdown select.  I am setting the ng-disabled property of the ui-select element to the state variable I use in the checkbox.  It is working fine, when I uncheck the box, the dropdown select is disabled, when I check the box, the dropdown select is enabled.

I want the default placeholder (when no items have been selected yet) to return whenever the dropdown select is disabled. That is, after selecting a dropdown item, it is displayed in the ui-select replacing the default placeholder. When the dropdown select is then disabled, I want the placeholder to replace the currently selected item. That way when the dropdown is enabled again, it starts with the placeholder.  I have tried different approached, but I am not conversant enough with angular to get this to work. If I enable the clear functionality, I get the 'X' and it will indeed clear the selection and return the placeholder, but I need to do that programatically from the checkbox callback.

So how do I force the placeholder of the ui-select element from the toggleSession click callback of the checkbox element?

I am really impressed with angular, but it is very painful trying to re-train my old thinking/habits to get my head around how to code the angular way.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated. This is my working code:

```
 <ui-select class="vic-session-select" ng-model="session.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="!useSession">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a session or search name...">
        {{$select.selected.date}}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{$select.selected.name}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="session in sessions | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, date: $select.search}">
        <div class="vic-overlay-select-list-item" ng-bind-html="session.date | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <span>&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
        <div class="vic-overlay-select-list-item" ng-bind-html="session.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
    <ui-select>
<md-checkbox class="vic-use-session-queue-checkbox" aria-label="Session Checkbox" 
       ng-checked="useSession" ng-click="toggleSession()">
   <span class="vic-session-checkbox-label">Use a predefined session with its overlays</span>
</md-checkbox>
```